# Definir componente de Vue

Tags: vue.js

soy consciente de que voy a hacer una pregunta muy básica pero no he conseguido encontrar información clara en internet. Necesito definir un componente Vue.js con las siguientes características:

```
- Nombre del componente: componente-test
- Propiedades o argumentos de entrada:
    elements: number
    color: string
- Datos:
    count: number. Valor inicial: 3
    values: array. Valores:
      {id: 1, name: 'AA'}
      {id: 2, name: 'BB'}
- Template: <h1>Título test</h1>
```

Mi duda principal es cómo puedo definir los datos y las propiedades y cómo puedo incluir un array en el componente. Esto es lo que he creado, pero no sé si es correcto:

```
Vue.component( 'componente-test', {
data: function () {
   return {
    count: 3,
    values: [
         {id:1, name: ‘AA’},
         {id:2, name: ‘BB’}
         ]
        }
    },
    props: {
      elements: number,
      color: string
   }

 template: '<h1>Título test</h1>'
})
```

Mil gracias por su tiempo!

Comment: Considera leer [ask] y checar el [tour], finalmente agregar que has intentado y dudas un tanto más específicas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El detalle es que cuando usas `props`, estos tienen que estar fuera del atributo `data`, es decir:

```js
Vue.component('componente-test', {
    data() {
        return {
            count: 3,
            values: [
              { id: 1, name: 'AA' }, 
              { id: 2, name: 'BB' }
            ]
        }
    },
    props: {
        elements: Number,
        color: String
    },
    template: '<h1>Título test, {{elements}}, {{color}}</h1>'
})

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    template: `
    <div>
        <componente-test :elements="1" color="red" ></componente-test>
        <componente-test :elements="2" color="blue" ></componente-test>
        <componente-test :elements="3" color="black" ></componente-test>
    </div>
    `
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

---

Considera que al usar `props` puedes definiros de la siguiente manera:

```
props: ['elements', 'color']
```

Esto quiere decir que tu componente *recibe* 2 cosas de cualquier tipo.

Si quieres restringir el tipo puedes usar:

```
props: {
  elements: Number,
  color: String
}
```

De modo que para usar tu componente puedes usar cualquiera de la siguientes opciones y el resultado será el mismo:

```
<componente-test :elements="2" color="blue" />
<componente-test v-bind:elements="2" color="blue" ></componente-test>
<componente-test :elements="2" color="blue" ></componente-test>
<componente-test :elements="2" :color="'blue'" ></componente-test>
```

> Notemos que:
>
> - Puedes usar `:elements` como una forma corta de escribir `v-bind:elements`, eso quiere decir que lo que le pasaremos a nuestro componente será algo más que un `String`, como `Array`, `Boolean`, `Object`, etc.
> - El caso especial de `String` se puede pasar como `color="blue"` o como `:color="'blue'"`.